# Checking the 32/64 bitness of a VB build

Tags: vb.net

I am working on a 64 bits machine but frequently have to build and test for both 32 (x86) and 64 (x64) bits (not Any CPU). It turns out to be quite easy to believe that one configuration is active when it's in fact the other. (Because of misuse of the Configuration Manager).

As this often causes me headaches and serious wastes of time, I'd like to have the application itself display whether it is built for 32 or 64 bits.

Nothings' simpler under C++, (`sizeof(int*)`), but I can't find a way that works under Visual Basic. Can you help ?

Note that I am not willing to know if the platform itself is 32 or 64 bits, just the build.

Comment: `Environment.Is64BitProcess` will tell you if it is running as a 64bit process, is that what you are after?

Comment: Great ! I just tried and it does what I need. Thanks.

Comment: I personally always liked IntPtr.Size = 8, much faster and gives the jitter optimizer a much easier time to produce better code.

Answer (score 0):

You have the same possibility in VB.net
Dim bits As Integer = IntPtr.Size * 8